# Problema con Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL para enviar un correo

Tags: android

Tengo este codigo:

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent Mail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            Mail.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));

            Mail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,"hola@gmail.com");
            Mail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC,"hola@gmail.com");
            Mail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"tema");
            Mail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"cuerpo correo");

            Mail.setType("message/rfc822");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(Mail,"send Email"));

        }
    });
```

lo que pasa es que cuando se ejecuta en la aplicacion de gmail muestra el asunto y el cuerpo, pero no muestra para quien va dirigido o la copia

podría ser algún problema de versión o algo así?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por si te sirve, yo lo que hago es que al remitente le mando un array, por si quiero enviarlo a varios a la vez. Por ejemplo, este código me funciona perfectamente:

```
                String[] TO = {"destino@tudestino.com"};
                String[] CC = {""};
                Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
                emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, TO);
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, CC);
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Aquí tu asunto");

                try {
                    startActivity(emailIntent);
                    finish();
                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(AjustesActivity.this, "No tienes ningún gestor de correo instalado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

Y de paso verifico si tiene algún gestor de correo instalado o no antes de realizar ninguna acción.

Ojo, para verificarlo, tienes que hacerlo sobre un dispositivo real, ya que sobre un emulador no suele funcionar bien. Imagino que por tema de configuraciones.

Suerte!